# Datagrid CheckBox Column Not able to Access the CheckBox Value

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

For some reason even though I check my checkbox in a datagrid (asp.net) control and click the linkbutton but when I read the checkbox value. It says unchecked.

```
  <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Selection">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox id="chkSelect" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>            
            </asp:TemplateColumn>     

     For Each dgi As DataGridItem In dgReceipts.Items

                Dim isChecked As Boolean = TryCast(dgi.FindControl("chkSelect"), CheckBox).Checked

    next
```

UPDATE 1:

I also tried to access the value of a textbox column and same issue. The value comes out to be blank.

Comment: You are rebinding in init or load.

Comment: I checked I am not binding on init or load.

Comment: Please add more code. You have not given enough to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

How are you binding your GridView?  Are you only binding if the page isn't posting back?  A post back will blow away your selections if you are binding, for example, in the Page Load event and not checking for post back.  Without seeing more code it is difficult to determine the exact cause, but usually not checking for post back in binding is this type of problem's root cause.

Comment: I am not binding inside the page_load. The user clicks the search button and then the grid is displayed. After that user check the checkboxes and press another linkbutton which fires the click event. There I try to access the checked checkboxes and textbox values and it returns me default values like false and String.empty

Answer (score 0):

You either have multiple lines with checkboxes and are seeing false on one of them or are rebinding the grid.  You will have to add more code to confirm.

Comment: This even happens when all the checkboxes are checked. I get false!